# PHP: using /dev folder on production server

Tags: php, development-environment, intranet

OK, likely a total noob question.

I've developed a very small-scale php intranet site for a low-income medical clinic I work at. I developed it on my own workstation using NetBeans and EasyPHP, and it works there.

We set up a new server box for production using Uniform Server (root: C:\UniServer\www) and then enabled my workstation to access that box through the network.

I put all the files into C:\UniServer\www\dev on the server box to see how the site would work on that machine before putting it up in the root folder for users to see. However, I'm running into a problem. Because the server defines the root of the project as C:\UniServer\www and not as C:\UniServer\www\dev, all of my urls that look something like "/Program/index.php" or "/Contact/index.php" in the source code end up pointing to the server root, not server/dev and are therefore broken.

Also in my index template (will appear in all visible files on the site), I have:

```
$ROOT_DIRECTORY = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
```

(I'm not sure I want to define it as a constant because I may use it in a heredoc block)

I use the `$ROOT_DIRECTORY` in places like

```
include("$ROOT_DIRECTORY/includes/standardpage.php");
```

and naturally, the same problem arises - unless I include  `. "/dev"` in the declaration above, none of it works.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious. Any help?

Do I have to set up a devserver or another server root in the /dev directory? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

> all of my urls that look something like "/Program/index.php" or "/Contact/index.php" in the source code end up pointing to the server root, not server/dev and are therefore broken.

Since your `$ROOT_DIRECTORY` variable looks fine, I can only assume that you're getting these errors because you are literally writing your anchors to point to `/Program/index.php` - where the prefixed `/` there directs the browser to the root of the server (whether it be `http://yourdomain.com` or `http://localhost`).

Your domain doesn't care about whether or not you use a dev folder for development, which is why it's often a good idea to use subdomains instead of subfolders for these environments.

**Anyway...** the way for you to fix your problem is to prepend the `$ROOT_DIRECTORY` variable to each of your links.

Instead of this:

```
<a href="/Program/index.php">Hello world!</a>
```

... do this:

```
<a href="<?=$ROOT_DIRECTORY?>/Program/index.php">Hello world!</a>
```

Comment: "Your domain doesn't care about whether or not you use a dev folder for development" ... exactly. How do I use subdomains? Remember I'm pretty new at this. Thanks.

Comment: "you are literally writing your anchors to point to /Program/index.php - where the prefixed / there directs the browser to the root of the server"   ... yes, that's the intention, and it works fine when I put all the files for the site in the actual root. Also I don't expect you to explain subdomains to me, but a link or two would be awesome. :)

Comment: Prepending $ROOT_DIRECTORY won't fix it in the /dev folder unless I modify that variable to include "/dev", which of course then won't work in the production version, so I'd have to do something like if(strrpos(getcwd(), "dev") { $ROOT_DIRECTORY .= "/dev" } which seems a little hackish to me.

Comment: It's not hackish, setting up a development environment usually requires a few lines of code in a config file somewhere, you ideally don't want to add code to every link or every line. If you set up a subdomain instead of a subfolder you can use the root directory there instead. Are you running this intranet over an IP address though? Subdomains will only work if you are using a domain name, not an IP address or localhost

Comment: Yeah, I just checked, subdomains aren't an option here. My supervisor suggested using a config file in each potential "root" directory that is read by my script and added to the root variable.